# What's is the best stack for cPanel continuous deployment?

Tags: git, deployment, sass

My current environment involving:

- Gulp (task automation)
- Sass
- Bitbucket (for version control)

But for deployment, I always manually override the files through FTP. And re-import the database.
The process is somehow not effective for me.

Can anyone please share their continuous deployment that is more effective than mine?

Thank you.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with cpanel / your host's specific configuration, what kind of access do you have? Do you have SSH? Can you run daemons on your account?

Comment: I have SSH, but truthfully our server is not the best. It doesn't have much thinking power. I think just 256mb ram, not possible to do any `npm install` or anything like that

Answer (score 0):

I made a WordPress development stack using Shipit JS. Maybe that can help. Feel to use it and/or post some issues if needed. Regards.

[WP-Jungle / Bonzai](https://github.com/wp-jungle/bonzai)